When firing the click function by cliking the child div, how can get the parent event?
const onMenuItemClick = (event) =>{
    console.log("onMenuItemClick data-id",event.target.getAttribute('data-id'));
}

html (JSX) is like this below,
One parent div which has two children div
<div onClick={onMenuItemClick} data-id="show">
         <div className={styles['contextIconBox']}>
          <img src={btn_delete} className={styles['contextIcon']}/></div>
          <div className={styles['contextLabel']}> myarea</div>
         </div>
</div>

When cliking this div onMenuItemClick is called
However data-id is not fetched(data-id is null),
I guess maybe, this is becasuse onMenuClick is fired but event is not the parent div?
How can I get dhe data-id here?

You're clicking on the nested DOM elements. Use parentNode or proper event delegation.

Add console.log(event.target) to see which element gets the onClick

@0Stone0 Thank you for your help, event.target is either of children div, but onMenuItemClick is called by them. but is it possible to get the data-id even child div is called??

@whitebear why don't you used currentTarget

You're nested DOM element is retrieving the onClick.
Use currentTarget to get the DOM element from which the current event handler is attached.
Or for more complex DOM setups, you might want to add a className to each menu-item and then use .closest('.menu-item') so search for the matching item.



const Example = () => {
    
   const onMenuItemClick = (event) =>{
        console.log("Clicked on ", event.currentTarget.dataset.id);
        console.log("Clicked on ", event.target.closest('.menu-item').dataset.id);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{'Example'}</h1>
            <div className='menu-item' onClick={onMenuItemClick} data-id="show">
                <div className='contextIconBox'>
                    <em className='contextIcon' />
                    <div> myarea</div>
                </div>    
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("react"));
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>




You can use currentTarget instead of target
const onMenuItemClick = (event) =>{
    console.log("onMenuItemClick data-id",event.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-id'));
}

